# Word or phrase to describe relation beween yourself and a step-parent's ex-spouse?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Is there a word or simple phrase to describe the relationship between yourself and a step-parent's ex-spouse?  Particularly, I'm seeking to address the case when the ex-spouse is a parent to your step-sibling.

Example:   Bob’s mother re-married to Alice’s father.  How should one appropriately refer to the relation between Bob, and Alice’s mother?

I’m trying to find something that’s appropriate for a relationship closer than “Bob’s step-sister’s mother” or “Bob’s step-father’s ex-wife” but not quite so close as to just call her “Bob’s mom”.

Comment: Interesting question. I've always been vexed at the similar issue of how to refer to my brother's wife's sister. She's my sister-in-law's sister, or my brother's sister-in-law, but to me she's what?

Comment: Even if you can find a good word or phrase, prepare to be misunderstood.  In a recent answer, I referred to my stepmother's father as my "step-grandfather"; at least one commenter changed this to "stepfather".

Answer (score 5):

There is good Yiddish word for this, `mishbucha`, which according to my Jewish friends, means someone who is related to you, usually in a complicated way.

Comment: According to Yiddish Dictionary Online, this word is `mishpokhe` and means "family" or "kin".  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm used to *mishpacha* (no 'b'; it's a 'p') describing the down-over-up of a couple's parents.  My parents are my husband's parents' *mishpacha* and vice-versa.  (This case is not served by the "in-law" form without additional modifiers.)  I don't know how common its usage is with step-relations, exes, and weird cousin Billy that no one wants to talk about.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... *stepmom once removed*? Except that would imply a generational difference. *Step-step-mom*?

As you can probably tell, there isn't an official term for this.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would call her "my stepsister's mother", since that is the relationship that is important to you. Also, anyone who takes a moment to think would figure out that you are not talking about your own mother OR stepmother, since you would have said so in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: there is none.

Long answer: really...there is none. There's not even [a single word to distinguish a blood relative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24434/how-can-i-know-the-exact-meaning-of-cousin-in-a-sentence) much less those separated by two steps of not being related.

Answer (score 1):

*In-law* would cover it, though possibly too general.   And yes, technically she isn't your *anything-in-law, but the word, in my experience, expands to cover cases like this.

Comment: I like to call not-quite-relatives of this sort (I have several myself) "out-laws".