# Is the "female" in "female cousin" redundant here?

Tags: adjectives, translation, grammatical-gender, kinship-terms

> "My female cousin working for a finance company was dismissed. Disappeared along with her job were her confidence and smiling face."

There is a very complicated system in Chinese for naming different relatives. For example, in Chinese, different words are used for a female cousin and a male cousin. Also, the word for an elder female cousin is different from the word for a younger one.

I'm having some trouble writing this sentence in English. I used "female cousin" in the first part, to translate the word that actually means "elder female cousin" in Chinese, but it still sounds awkward. I suspect that the "female" may be redundant too, because in the second part I use the pronoun "her".

Comment: 'Redundant' usually has a pejorative connotation. There is no 'ungrammaticality' or 'illogicality' in your sentence, though, as you say, 'female' is not necessary as this fact comes out later. I'd expect 'My cousin Ann ...' in colloquial English, unless there has to be an emphasis on 'female' (are you addressing discrimination, say?)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206117/why-are-there-no-male-or-female-terms-for-cousins-in-english

Comment: No, I am not addressing that issue.

Comment: A different issue: the way you use *disappeared...**were*** is not grammatical. You might use: Along with her job, her confidence and smiling face disappeared. Her confidence and smiling face disappeared along with her job. Along with her job, gone were her confidence and smiling face. There is new transitive euphemistic meaning of the verb *to disappear* borrowed from Spanish-speaking countries in South America: "to take someone away by force in order to imprison or kill them". "To be disappeared" in that sense is "to be taken away... etc".

Comment: Some words signifying relationships are gender-neutral in English. In fact, we need the phrases *boy friend* and *girl friend* for a similar reason. It is true, however, that other languages have gender-specific words/ terms.

Comment: @Kris The Chinese have _too many_ gender-specific word. Fun fact: nephew from your sister is called differently from nephew from your brother, which is called differently depending on whether it's your older/younger brother. Have fun. On the contrary, IIRC Chinese does not have a concept of "*boy*friend" or "*girl*friend", it merely has a "lover"

Comment: You're correct that for those two sentences together, you don't need 'female' to know the sex of your cousin, because it is specified by 'her'. But for the first sentence by itself, you don't know that. So if all you have is the first sentence and you need to convey the sex of your cousin, you must specify 'female'.

Comment: @Raestloz: A lot of languages have that; it's really a peculiarity of English that we have a single word meaning both "sister's son" and "brother's son". The age distinctions seem to be a bit less common, though.

Comment: @TRomano I think disappeared just needs to be changed to disappearing?  Though, I'm not sure I like the tense of either sentence...

Comment: @user3334690: Or we could rephrase: *Along with her job, the smile on her face and her confidence have disappeared.*  Her face itself has not disappeared.

Comment: I think you can omit "female" here.

Comment: @Raestloz While you're right that Chinese kinship terms are indeed highly specific, I wouldn't say that there is no concept of "boyfriend" / "girlfriend". 男朋友 and 女朋友 are literal translations of "boyfriend" and "girlfriend" — and they are common terms that are used the same way as in English.

Comment: @user51369 See my comment on Jon Hanna's answer.  Also, as a general rule in English, specifying the sex in a noun or adjective, and then following it by masculine or feminine pronouns isn't considered redundant; it's largely because the other words are pronouns, whereas the first is a noun or adjective, and because unlike several other languages, English has a very strong requirement to specify the subject in its own word (causing you to have to keep using the same pronouns and such over and over again).

Comment: @200_success I do not remember nan pengyou for boyfriend, I do remember airen though, I guess I'm mistaken

Answer (score 44):

This comes up a lot with *cousin* as many other languages have more words for different types of cousin than English, though not always in the same way as you say for the Chinese languages.

Generally, we just say "cousin" unless it's particularly relevant. If it was relevant we might be happy enough that the subsequent *her* does indicate her being female.

We might include it if it was particularly relevant, even given the subsequent information from *her*. E.g. if you suspected discrimination.

But in terms of translation, normally the natural way to talk about any such relative is just a bare "cousin".

Comment: To extend upon this, the use of "female" there implies that the speaker thinks this is important--that she was fired for being female.  Thus it's not only redundant but misinformation.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: …Unless the speaker indeed does think it was discriminatory, of course.

Comment: A good example to make this clearer is the following: saying "my female cousin" is a bit like saying "my blond cousin": it highlights the fact that the cousin has blond hair, and that this bit of information is stated explicitly because it is relevant.

Comment: One consideration would be the word-for-word accuracy of the translation; it looks like the OP is trying to balance about halfway in between a word-for-word translation and making the sentence sound natural in English.  "Female cousin" isn't redundant or unnatural at all, though "Elder female cousin" is unnatural by default.  I agree that adding the word "female" makes it sound like her sex is particularly relevant, but it doesn't do so very strongly; the reader should just be slightly curious if it's relevant at that point...

Comment: ...I've heard "female cousin" used in spoken English on a couple of rare occasions when the sex wasn't relevant, and it actually sounded natural.  If the OP is doing something that is advertised as a translation, they'd have to carefully weigh whether it's good to strike that kind of balance here.

Comment: @JanHudec It's only included because it's a literal translation of the Chinese word.  Thus I see no reason to think he considers the firing to be due to discrimination.

Answer (score 7):

Spanish also makes this kind of distinction: `prima` and `primo`, between a female and male cousin.

In English, we do not care about the gender unless it is relevant to the topic.  Otherwise, why bother to say it?  If I said "My female cousin got a new job today", someone might then expect to find out what my male cousin must be doing.  It just sounds odd to a native since we generally do not care if the person was a man or woman.  English is very gender-neutral because we don't want to emphasize that it matters someone is a male or female, and you'll probably get strange looks, or someone correcting you, if you continually add it in when gender is irrelevant to the discussion.  Or they may think you are a feminist for adding `female` - especially if you emphasize it.  It is simply more correct to say "My cousin ..." than "My female cousin", in English, for these reasons.

Answer (score 7):

This is not just a gender issue.  In English, [cousin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin) is incredibly non-specific (even when you take into account that *first* cousin is usually implied).  When translating [Chinese kinship terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_kinship#Common_extended_family_and_terminology) to English, there is no escaping the loss of information without awkwardness — unless you are talking about your father, mother, husband, wife, son, or daughter.

Assuming that you meant to translate from 表姐 with perfect precision, you *could* say something ridiculous like

> My female first cousin, who is older than me, in the same generation as me, and is not my father's brother's daughter, …

Once you accept the fact that you're going to lose precision in translation, you might as well accept that "My cousin" is the natural translation, especially since your cousin's gender is clear from the context provided in the following sentence.  It is not idiomatic to include *any* additional information in English unless the information is specifically relevant to what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 6):

By order of appearance, it's the word "her" that is redundant, but English doesn't have an appropriate gender-neutral alternative.  That means that, strictly speaking, "female" provides information that is already available, albeit only later.

Whether this should be considered redundant depends on whether that information is important, and whether it's important that it be shared at that point.  Personally, I like removing "female" and letting the deferred pronoun subtly provide the extra info on her gender.

A great value of asking this question comes from considering why it matters at all that your cousin is female?  Is it important to the rest of the writing?  Are you - or is your reader - left uncomfortable with either not knowing, or with that knowledge delayed? If so, is that discomfort usefully transgressive, or merely annoying?

It's almost always possible to recast without gender, and often (almost) unnoticeably:

> Dismissed from a finance company was my cousin, whose confidence and 
>   smiling face left as well.

or

> Dismissed from a finance company was my cousin, whose confidence and 
>   smiling face - and boyfriend - left as well.

or

> Dismissed from a finance company was my cousin, whose confidence and 
>   smiling face, - and boyfriend - left as well. 
>   Fortunately, he soon found another.

Comment: Very good point!

Comment: If, in your second example, "boyfriend" is intended to imply that the cousin is female, then that's a heteronormative assumption. Your third example is incomprehensible.

Comment: @200_success - in #2, "boyfriend" is intended to convey that the boyfriend left.  That is all.  It is, secondarily, intended to roust out heteronormative assumptions, as you observed.  
In that light, "he soon found another" is the payoff: my cousin was a boy, and he soon found another... boyfriend and/or job.  :)  
The point of my examples was to demonstrate the opportunities in deferring information.

Comment: Upvoted because of the messing about with the hetero-centric worldview :-) People still make hetero-centric assumptions all to easily.

Comment: Gender assumptions (and the challenging thereof) aside, there's still something wrong with the third example. "confidence and smiling face, - boyfriend -" isn't a valid way to punctuate a list of nouns. And the second sentence also leaves slight ambiguity whether "he" is the cousin or the boyfriend. One assumes we're more sympathetic to the cousin, so wouldn't say "fortunately" if it's the boyfriend, therefore it's the cousin. But who knows, maybe we think the boyfriend deserved happiness too despite apparently ditching our cousin just for losing his/her job!

Comment: Thanks, @SteveJessop for catching my typo. Should have been "and boyfriend" in 2 and 3. Make more sense now?

Comment: I need to say something about your questions in the third paragraph of your post. These questions actually explore more deeply the difference between Chinese and English. Suppose my readers are Chinese, I would say that they will feel very uncomfortable for the delayed "her" and for the vagueness concerning the fact whether he/she is older than you or the person you describe. The superficial reason is that Chinese people know all these information about their relatives whenever they use the word standing for those relatives.

Comment: @user51369: yes, thanks. That was part of my thinking, though my knowledge of the assumptions brought by non-native English-speakers is limited, so I tried to broaden the questions beyond that.  I agree that the questions are both interesting and profound.

Comment: @user51369 Are you sure that delaying gender information by a few words would make a Chinese audience uneasy? Spoken Chinese is basically gender-neutral when it comes to personal pronouns (他/她 sound the same), and that doesn't cause discomfort. The same goes for Chinese personal names — they are less easily gendered than most English names.

Comment: @200_success: you are right on noticing that phenomenon in Chinese.A western professor working in the field of Chinese philosophy said to me that for two decades he had met lots of Chinese friends very fluent in English, but none could be immune from  confusing she and he. But as for your second comment that Chinese personal names are less easily gendered. I have some reservations. In English, all personal names's gender is identifiable. There is no exception. In Chinese, confusions sometimes happen.But the principle  is crystal clear,a personal name should be able to hint out the gender.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.

Redundancy is if you're re-iterating a point. "Cousin" is a gender neutral word and therefore clarifying the gender of the subject is not redundant. The gender can be implied by the usage of "her", but that does not make the usage of "female" redundant.

Comment: But then it is redundant, as it adds nothing more. It could be a useful redundancy (to clarify) or it could be useless even if it wasn't redundant (if we didn't have anything providing the same information but didn't care anyway) but it's definitely redundant.

Comment: It's not. "Her" is the proper way of referencing a female subject. If the cousin is, in fact, a male, the sentence then goes from "avoiding redundancy" to "outright wrong"

Comment: But then "female cousin" would be equally wrong, so that isn't really to the point.

Comment: The best I can guess is that you have an unusually narrow concept of redundancy. Maybe you consider "female sister" redundant because the **word** *sister* already contains the concept of *female*. But redundancy doesn't operate solely at a word level. *Any* unnecessary repetition of *any* information is redundant. In fact, I would argue that "reiterating a point" is **not** redundant, because the speaker feels the point is important enough that it needs repeating. That is, the repetition is serving a meaningful purpose.

Comment: @JohnY I agree that I should have added "without any meaningful purpose" on my answer, because that is the definition of redundancy. See what I did there? ;).

Comment: @JonHanna Like I said in the comment, "her" is the proper way of referencing a female subject. Declaring a subject as female beforehand is, therefore, not redundant, because the usage of "her" is not re-iterating the point, it's just referencing the subject properly

Comment: What does whether or not it was "re-iterating the point" have to do with whether or not it's redundant?

Comment: @JonHanna because that is the definition of redundancy. If you only do something once it's definitely not redundant. I do not see how you can assert that redundancy can occur when something only happens once.

Comment: The point is `My female sister lifted her bag` could be written `She lifted her bag` or `My sister lifted her bag`.  Yes, you need the subject/pronoun pair, no debate there. But the adjective "female" is redundant to the subject/pronoun pair because the information the subject is a female is already there.  Do you understand now why "female" in "female cousin" and "her job" from the OP example are redundant?  "Cousin" and "her" are the subject/pronoun pair, "female" is the unnecessary, redundant adjective to the pronoun's meaning.

Comment: @vapcguy you're trying to compare the usage of a perfectly gender-specific subject with the usage of a correct reference to the subject itself, which are completely different things. Without the "female" part you can use "her" and "his" to reference the cousin in the next phrase, but by using "female" you can only use "her". The redundancy, therefore, is not because we add "female". Can you please tell me any other option but to use "her" should "female cousin" be used?

Comment: @Raestloz, read that last sentence you just typed, again.  I think you made my exact point.  Because there is no other option than to use "her" if it's a female cousin, the "female" is redundant - "her" already describes the cousin's gender.

Comment: @vapcguy ah, and that is where you're wrong. A genderqueer person might be referenced with "her". "Her" implies, but does not explain. EDIT: just in case you start talking about "then you can refer to genderqueer as female too!" not really. The adjective "her" may be used simply because someone refuse to use "they" due to its plural connotation and fall back to binary sex adjective, using "female" to identify a "genderqueer" is outright wrong, it defies genderqueer definition in the first place

Comment: @Raestloz, in English, at least in the U.S., if you go around saying `My genderqueer cousin lifted her/his/their bag`, people will look at you funny and believe that is WAY too much information. People will accept that the cousin identifies with the female gender simply with the `her`, or with the male gender with `his`, or you can say `their` but that may raise eyebrows.  But if the person definitely does not identify with either gender, the English-speaker you are talking to will surely beg you not to say `genderqueer`, unless they are really into learning about that sort of thing.

Answer (score -3):

I am not an expert in English, but I do think simply "My [cousin sister](http://english_dialects.enacademic.com/11936/cousin_sister) working for a....", makes it more sensible for reading and hearing. This is a common expression in Indian English dialects.

Comment: "Cousin sister" does sound fairly natural, and I could readily see it catching on, at least in dialects of English influenced by some other language already using such a construction. But as @rumtscho correctly notes, it's not currently a standard or generally understood kinship term in most varieties of English.

Comment: "cousin sister" exists in Indian English and Australian English. [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/submission/1501/cousin-sister) (new word suggestion): "'Cousin sister ' (likewise, cousin brother) is widely used in Andhra Pradesh and other states of India." As the OP doesn't specify a particular variety of English, Tilak's answer is completely valid.

Comment: [Amritt Indian English dictionary](http://www.amritt.com/india-english-dictionary/cousin-sister/) confirms it ("Cousin sister: Cousin, female"), although [LearningIndia has a slightly different definition](http://learningindia.in/references/indian-english-dictionary/): "Cousin-brother/Cousin-sister – a relative you consider your brother or sister because of growing up very close to them, but you don’t actually have the same mother and father (South Indian)"

Comment: @AE OK, sorry, I mistakenly assumed that Tilak is literally translating it from another language, not giving an example from an English dialect I have not been exposed to. I'm removing my downvote.

Comment: "Cousin sister" doesn't exist in American English, and I doubt in U.K. English.  I had never heard of it.  Did you mean "cousin's sister"?  I'd have no clue who you meant if you said this.

Comment: "cousin sister" isn't valid Australian English. To my Aussie ears, it's a contradition: a given person could be your cousin, or your sister, but not both.